# Can't get POSTFIX working in virtualmin ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, email, debian

For weeks now I am trying to configure the virtualmin postfix mail server in a vps ubuntu 18 server, to send corporate email messages of the contact@pixi.com.ar style but I can not receive the messages from gmail, nor connect thunderbird to the server, I attach the postfix main.cf which is where I think the error is, when I send emails from usermin they get to gmail but to the spam folder

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.key.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = vps41250600.local 
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = vps41250600.local, $myhostname, localhost.localdomain, vps.server.local, localhost.server.local, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = dane
allow_percent_hack = no
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
```

Answer (score 0):

Compadre hace unos días me vi con este mismo problema. Si tienes un VPS hay formas más sencillas de montar tu propio MTA como Iredmail (te toma 10 minutos) [mira aquí](https://docs.iredmail.org/install.iredmail.on.debian.ubuntu.html)

Para detectar problemas en la configuración a parte de revisar los logs en /var/log/mail.log puedes utilizar [esta herramienta](http://mxtoolbox.com/). Es posible que tengas el correo configurado como un openrelay lo cual hace que google no confíe en ti pero mucho peor puede que te empiecen a indexar en listas negras.

Espero esto te ayude.

In english so everyone can understand me.

Compadre a few days ago I saw myself with this same problem. If you have a VPS there are simpler ways to mount your own MTA like Iredmail (it takes 10 minutes) [see here](https://docs.iredmail.org/install.iredmail.on.debian.ubuntu.html)

To detect problems in the configuration apart from checking the logs in /var/log/mail.log you can use [this tool](http://mxtoolbox.com/). It is possible that you have mail configured as an openrelay which makes google do not trust you but much worse may start to index you in blacklists.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Aparte que el VPS este saliendo por un firewall, o que su router lo tome como una IP rara(dinámica) y no como lo que se quiere mostrar como @pixi.com.ar, y este domain debería estar por lógica como una IP estática para que GMAIL no banee la lista de correos de pixi.com.ar

Comment: Questions and answers should be in English. I do realize you want to help the asker who may or may not speak English. Still, could you [edit] and add an English translation for everyone else?

Comment: I have added an english translation

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a firewall preventing connections to your mail server. Port 25 must be available from other's, to test you are a real mail server and to deliver mails to you.